# Problema de acceso por ftp

Tags: wordpress, servidor, ftp, ssh, vpn

Recientemente me dieron a modificar un proyecto en `Wordpress`,  ocurre que utilizo el `loop` de `Wordpress`, hay un error de sintaxis que es algo normal, e intento acceder por `FTP` para acomodar el código, pero el `FTP` no funciona, me comunico con el project manager y me dice que ellos no saben que ocurre y me comentan que tiene algo que ver con que es un servidor `VPN` y por eso da problemas al acceder mediante `FTP`, pues no he trabajado administrando servidores entonces tengo la duda si a alguien le ha pasado algo así antes y saben que puedo hacer, se los agradecería.

Comment: Que el servidor tenga corriendo un servidor VPN no implica que vayas a tener problemas con un servidor FTP. Quizá tengan filtrado el acceso FTP desde Internet y lo tengan habilitado únicamente a través de la red local y los clientes conectados por VPN para mejorar(?) la seguridad. Pero es por una política de seguridad que han decidido implantar, no porque tener un servidor VPN implique necesariamente usarla para acceder a un servidor.

Comment: pues si tenia que entrar con el vpn de cisco, aun asi sigue dandome problemas, guardo codigo en la plantilla de wordpress pero al ir a la pagina web no se visualiza a pesar de que si veo el archivo veo que el codigo esta, es extraño para mi... @OscarGarcia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema de una `VPN` es que tienes que estar conectada a ella para poder acceder a los recursos de esa red.

Explicación de VPN: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_privada_virtual

Esto es, por mucho que te den la `IP` y los datos `FTP` de ese servidor, a menos que estés dentro de su red, no vas a poder conectarte a él.

Necesitas que te den acceso a la `VPN`, registrarte dentro de ella y luego ya podrás conectarte a ese servidor.

Si estas en un Windows existen muchos programas que te ayudan a conectarte a una `VPN`, [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html) por ejemplo.